How to show that $\displaystyle\arccos{\alpha} = 2\arctan{\sqrt{\frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}}}$ for $\alpha\in (-1,1]$?
I was working through a solution for an integral, and one of the last steps made use of this identity, which I have never encountered and struggled to find anywhere. I've tried messing around with some of the more common identities involving inverse cosine, inverse sine, and inverse tangent, but have just been going in circles. Can someone give me a tip on how I might start to prove this identity?
Some of the identities I have been exploring:
$\displaystyle\tan{(\arccos{(x)})} = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$
$\displaystyle\cos{(\arctan{(x)})} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$
$\displaystyle\arctan{(x)} = 2\arctan{(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}})}$
And a few others which really took me nowhere, but are fairly common if you google around for inverse trig identities.

If you take $\cos$ on both sides, is the resultant equation true? If yes, then check the domain of the values to ensure we don't end up with something like $ \cos \theta = \cos - \theta$.

Hint: this is due to half angle formula, namely
$$
\cos(2x)=\frac{1-\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}
$$
Try to simplify this and apply inverse trig functions.

Since $$\cos2x=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$$
then let $\tan^2x=\alpha$, therefore,
$$\cos2x=\frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}$$
$$\Rightarrow 2x=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)$$
Putting $x=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\alpha}$, we get:
$$2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\alpha}=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)$$
Further substitution from $\alpha=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$ gives us:
$$\frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}=y$$
Therefore,
$$\cos^{-1}y=2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-y}{1+y}}$$
That proves your identity.
